# Exceptions that reflect error codes of a remote service

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm working with an external service which reports errors by code.

I have the list of error codes and the associated messages. Say, the following categories exist: authentication error, server error.

What is the smartest way to implement these errors in Python so I can always lookup an error by code and get the corresponding exception object?

---

Here's my straightforward approach:

```
class AuthError(Exception): 
    pass

class ServerError(Exception): 
    pass

map = {
  1: AuthError,
  2: ServerError
}

def raise_code(code, message):
    """ Raise an exception by code """
    raise map[code](message)
```

Would like to see better solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is correct, except that `map` should be renamed something else (e.g. `ERROR_MAP`) so it does not shadow the builtin of the same name.

---

You might also consider making the function *return* the exception rather than raising it:

```
def error(code, message):
    """ Return an exception by code """
    return ERROR_MAP[code](message)

def foo():
    raise error(code, message)
```

By placing the `raise` statement inside `foo`, you'd raise the error closer to where the error occurred and there would be one or two less lines to trace through if the stack trace is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create a polymorphic base class which, being instantiated, actually produces a subclass that has the matching code.

This is implemented by traversing `__subclasses__()` of the parent class and comparing the error code to the one defined in the class. If found, use that class instead.

Example:

```
class CodeError(Exception):
    """ Base class """
    code = None  # Error code

    def __new__(cls, code, *args):
        # Pick the appropriate class
        for E in cls.__subclasses__():
            if E.code == code:
                C = E
                break
        else:
            C = cls  # fall back
        return super(CodeError, cls).__new__(C, code, *args)

    def __init__(self, code, message):
        super(CodeError, self).__init__(message)

# Subclasses with error codes
class AuthError(CodeError):
    code = 1

class ServerError(CodeError):
    code = 2

CodeError(1, 'Wrong password')  #-> AuthError
CodeError(2, 'Failed')  #-> ServerError
```

With this approach, it's trivial to associate error message presets, and even map one class to multiple codes with a dict.